# Gridview Columns from an Array in Yii2

Tags: arrays, gridview, yii2

I have a gridview for a dataProvider that i create in view from an JSON response from an API and i want to show some columns and not all from the data structure that i'm getting, so i have a fields array and want to create columns by the array.

I create an array like this

```
$array=['column1','column2','column3'];
```

and when i use in columns parameter gives me an error

I tried like a string too but not success.
like this

```
$array="'column1','column2','column3'";



echo GridView::widget([
       'id' => 'prec_inc_grid',
        'columns' => [ 
            $array,
         ],]);
```

may show the well formed grid view but gives me this error

Setting unknown property: yii\grid\DataColumn::0

I suppose that is because the array is something like this

```
Array ( [0] => column1 [1] => column2 [2] => column3)
```

Comment: how are you creating the array to feed the `GridView` ? also show the response you are getting from the API

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to, because the JSON decode process was right, it was the [ ] after the " 'columns'=>" i deleted it and was 'columns'=>$array, and run perfect. Thanks.